# How many iterations for Pollard's $p-1$ with $p = r^k + 1$ for prime $r$?

Tags: factoring, pollard-rho

$p$ and $q$ are large primes.
What is the lowest upper bound for the number of iterations for Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm for factoring $N = pq$, provided that $p = r^k + 1$, for a prime $r$, and $r^k + 1 < q < r^{k+1}$?

Comment: $\pi(\sqrt[l]n)$ with $l$ being the lower bound you place on $k$ (and $\pi(x)$ being the prime counting function, ie the number of all primes less than or equal to $x$).

Comment: You may want to provide a reference to a description of the algorithm for which you want to find out the number of iterations, so we can be sure to all talk about the same loop...

Comment: Note that there are only 5 known primes of the form $r^k+1$ with $r$ prime; we know that if there is a sixth, it would be quite huge; more than $2^{8589934592}$

Comment: @SEJPM look at http://robin.pollak.io/wizard_factoring.pdf under the algorithm "Wizards don't exist" step 3.

Comment: @poncho that's fine, this is a theoretical question provided that this condition occurs.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the lowest upper bound for the number of iterations for Pollard's $p-1$ algorithm for factoring $N = pq$, provided that $p = r^k + 1$, for a prime $r$, and $r^k + 1 < q < r^{k+1}$?

Assuming that $p$ is prime, and that $N$ is smaller than 8 billion bits in length, then step 3 of the referenced algorithm will take at most 17 iterations before exiting via condition (a) or condition (b).

Comment: Care to show how did you reach that?

Comment: @oleiba: we always have $p$ be one of 3, 5, 17, 257 or 65537 - a simple examination of the algorithm shows that, at $r=17$ (if not before), we'll always have $a^{r!} - 1$ being a multiple of $p$, and so $d > 1$ (and so the loop will exit, either at iteration 17 or earlier than that)

Comment: Thanks. That's a good answer but I'm interested in even a lower upper bound dependant on k, and without assuming the size of $p$ (even though I acknowledge that it needs to be huge to exceed this set of known primes)